# When do formal power series coincide?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, power-series

Suppose we have two formal power series

$$A(z_1,\ldots ,z_n),B(z_1,\ldots ,z_n)\in\mathbb{C}[[z_1^{\pm 1},\ldots , z_n^{\pm 1}]],$$

where $n>1$.
Hence we can write the given series as

$$A(z_1,\ldots ,z_n)=\sum_{i_1,\ldots ,i_n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_{i_1,\ldots ,i_n} z_1^{i_1}\cdots z_n^{i_n}\quad\text{and}\quad B(z_1,\ldots ,z_n)=\sum_{i_1,\ldots ,i_n\in\mathbb{Z}} b_{i_1,\ldots ,i_n} z_1^{i_1}\cdots z_n^{i_n},$$

where  $a_{i_1,\ldots ,i_n},b_{i_1,\ldots ,i_n}$ are some complex numbers. Suppose there exists a disc

$$
D(x,r)=\left\{z=(z_1,\ldots ,z_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n\,:\,d(x,z)<r\right\}
$$

for some $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and positive integer $r$ such that both $A(z_1,\ldots ,z_n)$ and $B(z_1,\ldots ,z_n)$ converge on the disc $D(x,r)$ and such that $A(z)=B(z)$ for all $z\in D(x,r)$.

Do such (or any similar) assumptions imply that all coefficients of the given series coincide, i.e. can we conclude that
$$
a_{i_1,\ldots ,i_n} =b_{i_1,\ldots ,i_n}
\quad\text{
for all integers}\quad i_1,\ldots ,i_n\in\mathbb{Z}?$$

Comment: I'm not sure what the usual definitions are, but if, e.g., $z_1 z_1^{-1}$ is defined to be equal to $1$, then a proof suggests itself.

Comment: It looks like an application of analytic extension.  $A-B=0$ everywhere on the disk, so must be $0$ everywhere.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{C}[[z_1^{\pm 1},\ldots , z_n^{\pm 1}]]$ doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helpful comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That a $n$-variable Laurent series
$$f(z)=\sum_{\alpha \in \Bbb{Z}^n}a_\alpha z^\alpha$$ converges on some disk $|z-x|<r$ means that for all $z$ in the disk the $a_\alpha z^\alpha$ have exponential decay as $|\alpha|\to \infty$, whence the series converges on the whole annulus $\{ z,\exists \theta\in \Bbb{R}^n,|e^{i\theta}z-x|<r\}$.

If $f=g$ on the disk then by analytic continuation $f=g$ on the annulus.

Conclude from $$a_\alpha = \frac1{(2i\pi)^n}\int_{|z_1|=|x_1|}\ldots \int_{|z_n|=|x_n|}\frac{f(z)}{z_1^{\alpha_1+1}\ldots z_n^{\alpha_n+1}}dz_1\ldots dz_n$$